# How do I fork tensorflow serving and fork the submodules as well?

Tags: linux, git, github, tensorflow-serving

I apologize if this is a noob question, but I wanted to know the proper way of doing this. So I am working with tensorflow-serving and it contains 2 sub-modules, tf_models and tensorflow. When I go about forking tensorflow-serving and then clone my forked version, it seems that when I proceed to add any files to the submodules, I do not have access. When I go about git adding the files in the sub-modules and then proceeding to root (tensorflow-serving) repo and then add from there and commit/push it says everything pushed fine but when I select the sub-module from git, I get a 404 error.

In looking at this closer, it seems to be an issue of the sub-modules still referring to the original tf_models or tensorflow repo and the only thing that is forked seems to be the root tensorflow-serving path.

Right now I am using this myself, so I believe that if I just delete the git files in the sub-modules, I will probably solve my issue here however I believe this will cause not only problems with me trying to get the latest from those sub-modules, but also will raise an issue should I get to the point of requesting a pull request.

One of the other approaches I was thinking about doing was forking the tf_models repo as well as the tensorflow repo and then modify the tensorflow-serving gitmodules file to point to my paths.

I am posting here so I know the proper way of doing this as I believe that I could hack something but would prefer to know the right way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The repo I forked was https://github.com/tensorflow/serving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the submodule tensorflow (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) and tf_modules (https://github.com/tensorflow/models) are also belongs to user tensorflow’s repositories on github which you don't have permission, you also need to fork the two repo if you want make changes on them.

Then fork the serving repo with submodules by `git clone <fork serving URL> --recursive`. And change the submodules remote by below steps:

```
cd tensorflow
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <fork tensorflow URL>
cd ..
cd tf_models
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <fork tf_models URL>
cd..
```

If you want make changes for tensorflow/tf_models, just cd in the folder and commit changes, then use `git push origin branchname` to push.

Comment: Thank you so much Marina! I have been trying a number of solutions I was guessing at but nothing still seemed to work as expected. By changing the gitmodules file last night i was able to get it to somewhat work but it still wasn't pointing at the branch and felt like a clunky way of doing things. This is a great answer and I thank you for taking the time to help!